# Can keycloak provide login for the tools exposed behind it

Tags: security, authentication, keycloak, openid-connect

We have set up few tools in a cluster. We are using keycloak as the OIDC provider for end user authentication of these tools. Once a user logs into keycloak, is there any way in which these credentials can be passed to the tools, so that once the user is redirected to the tool, he will be auto-logged into the tool as well?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is the main point of Open ID Connect (OIDC) - Single sign-on (SSO) protocol. But credentials (user login/password) are not exposed by Keycloak. User identity in the access/identity token is exposed only.

Comment: So is there a way in which we can use the generated tokens to login to the tool? Tools ultimately need the credentials to be passed right? So just trying to understand how tokens can be used for achieving this.

Comment: There are a lot of good links here: https://github.com/thomasdarimont/awesome-keycloak  It comes down to using the token you get back from keycloak to authorize the user in your application. There are a lot of different ways to do this so there is no single right answer.